# Windows program running under WINE not seeing external USB device

Tags: usb, wine

I have installed a program to read from a temperature data logger that is MS-Windows based.

The program itself runs fine, however I can't see the data logger.

So I executed:

```
sudo udevadm monitor
```

I can see that Ubuntu recognizes the device, however either WINE or the program does not see the device. Is there a way to allow WINE to see the USB device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wine doesn't support access to USB devices by Windows programs running through it. After all, it's an emulator for Windows userspace APIs, not for device driver or other kernel API, nor is it a virtual machine.

You'll need to find a program that runs on Linux natively or use a virtual machine with Windows instead.

*Edit for people asking if that is still the case: **yes**. The underlying issue is a deliberate design choice regarding WINE's architecture. Any changes to that would be a drastic deviation from the current project goals.*

Comment: My win program inside wine can see I inserted the device. It doesn't connect properly though.

Comment: @viyps: You may be able to access files on a USB drive but only for the same reason that Wine allows access to files on internal drives, i. e. through Linux’ virtual file system.

Comment: is this still true?

Comment: Thanks @DavidFoerster! Since I wanted this specifically to update the firmware of my Arturia MIDI Controller, I ended up installing Windows on a Gnome Cubes virtual machine. Recommend that for anyone with a similar problem.